# How to add categories to page editor?

Tags: metabox

I'm trying to add the categories selector to the "page" editor workspace. The code below does the trick, however, none of the values are saved with the page.

Any help much appreciated!

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_categories_meta_box');
function my_post_categories_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('categorydiv', __('Categories'),      
   'post_categories_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'core');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to register the `category` taxonomy for the page `post_type` with [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type).

This does the trick:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse34528_add_page_cats' );
function wpse34528_add_page_cats()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
```

Comment: +1 Excellent! Is my code above sufficient or is there another way to do that as well?

Comment: You actually don't need the code you posted.  Just using the snippet I posed will add the meta box and make sure the stuff gets saved, etc.

Comment: Incredible. Why doesn't WP come this way out of the box?